# Is it possible to prevent component unmounting during modal page transitions animated with CSSTransition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

Navigating to and from a modal route `login` (`LoginModal`) the underlying page component `list` (`List`) will not be unmounted. What is good.

But wrapping the `List` page within a `CSSTransition` leads always to unintentional unmounts of this `List` component.

Even in the `react-transition-group` documentation is written: **By default the child component stays mounted after it reaches the 'exited' state.**

I think it has something to do with concurrently appearing and disappearing components.

Here you can see the declared routes:

```
...
<TransitionGroup>
  <CSSTransition
    key={location.key}
    classNames="fade"
    timeout={1000}
  >
    <div>
      <Switch location={location}>
        <Route exact path="/items/:id([0-9]+)" component={Item} />
        <Route path="/items" component={List} />
        <Route render={() => <div>Not Found</div>} />
      </Switch>
      <Route exact path="/items/login" component={LoginModal} />
    </div>
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
...
```

No unmounts without `CSSTransition`: https://codesandbox.io/embed/l57510x9jq

Unwanted unmounts with `CSSTransition`: https://codesandbox.io/embed/m0qo4xvwj

Is there a way to prevent this behavior and the subsequent remounts and render calls?